# possible for flash widget to send POST request to an external domain?

Tags: flash

is it possible for flash widge on site a.com to send POST request to b.com ?

If so, couldn't this be quite dangerous ? A user would be performing POST to an unknown host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but the other domain would have to serve a [crossdomain.xml](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html) policy file.  And if you think about it: Every time you hit a button on any page, you could be sending a hidden form to an unknown host.  Also, once things are sent to a server, there is no way of telling what happens to them afterwards - they could be forwarded anywhere.  So yes, it's dangerous.  But it's no more or less dangerous than any other activity on the internet.